# Updating Data in PDO Not successful

Tags: php, pdo

I got a problem when setting up a form to update user data on my blog using PDO.

Change a lot of code From afternoon till now has not been completed. But it seems this is already almost as if the html is made like this:

```
<textarea name="noid" id="noid"> </textarea>
```

On the noid not related to anything in the database, but instead there was little effect. while if using `newdata` instead become damaged.

the result will erase data if you've previously entered. According to you what is missing from my code?

```
public function runQuery($sql)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt;
}


    if(isset($_POST['newdata']))
    {
    $id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
    $newdata = $_POST['newdata'];
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("UPDATE users SET newdata=:newdata WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':newdata'=>$newdata));
    $myUser=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form method="post" name="newdata">
<div class="center">
<p><textarea name="newdata" id="newdata"></textarea></p>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Save" name="update"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: `$stmt->execute` then `prepare`, then `$stmt->execute` again. Do you understand what's happenning in your code?

Comment: No, I just know pdo. how should my code?